# what is the best will or going to

Tags: will-vs-going-to, future-tense

**Are you going to be sick** if you eat that? This clause "are you going to" is a future prediction so shouldn't it be better to use **will**

Is going to used as the event "being sick" is about to happen very soon
this sentence was alone no context it is an example

http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Going_To.htm

Comment: "get sick" would be better than "be sick". Since you aren't sick yet, your statement involves a (possible) change of state, not a static state.

Comment: @user3169 "be sick" means to throw up in BrE. So, the OP's sentence is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 'to be going to' and 'will' are directly interchangeable, but there are times when they are not.

In your example, the are interchangeable.

In the following example the are not interchangeable:

> I am going to France for my holiday.

You cannot replace 'going to' with 'will' in that sentence.

Comment: @James The reason that you cannot replace **going to** with **will** in the sentence you give is because the former is used to mean **travelling to** and it's not followed by a verb as in **going to see** (where **going to** is used to introduce the main verb rather than acting as the main verb itself.).

Comment: @userr2684291 *Will you be sick if you eat that?* and *Are you going to be sick if you eat that?* are perfectly acceptable. I was commenting on the sentence in the *question*, not the new example in the *answer*. (Which is an exception, and makes a specific point.) And, yes, I *do* say, variously, *it looks like it will rain* and *it looks like it's going to rain*. As well as *It's going to rain* and *it will rain*. Within each pair, they mean effectively the same thing.

Comment: @Ronald Sole I agree with your comment. I was simply trying to ensure that the OP was aware that 'going to' cannot always be replaced by 'will', and I used the first example that came to mind in the late hours of the evening.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural to use "going to" in this context.

One sense of the "going to" future is to talk about future events that occur as a result or consequence of current conditions.  So if you are asking "Do the current conditions of nausea indicate that you are likely to be sick in the future?", you would ask "are you going to be sick".

"Will" is a fairly neutral future tense, but it sometimes is used to suggest "future events that occur as a result of your choice".  So "will you be sick" seems less likely, as it has shades of "is it your choice to be sick in the future".

Grammatically both are correct, and there isn't much difference. But I suspect most native speakers would instinctively choose "Are you going to be sick" more often that "Will you be sick", for this reason.